# Открыть скрытую страницу

Tags: javascript

Нужно открыть страницу в браузере, выполнить действия и закрыть ее.

Я использовал `window.open`, но этот метод открывает страницу в новой вкладке или окне, и юзер видит это. К примеру - это очень мешает при просмотре фильмов и прочего.

Как открыть страницу так, чтобы юзер не видел ее открытия, или же как использовать `document.getElementById('id').click();` без открытия страницы/окна?

Comment: Ваша задача звучит очень странно. Зачем?

Comment: То есть прям как Вы хотите сделать точно нельзя, вот только мне кажется Вы не понимаете как веб работает.

Comment: Я пишу расширение для google chrome. Знаю и видел что как-то это работает у людей. Т.е. например расширение может делать то что я хочу, но при этом страница не открывается. Возможно я не так задаю вопрос, но если бы я мог прямо сказать что мне нужно, я бы и с гуглом справился. Думал кто-то помет.

Comment: В общем видимо вам надо сделать какие-то действия, которые происходят при нажатии на кнопку обычно, так?

Comment: Мне нужно собственно нажать на кнопку. Просто на определенной странице нажать на кнопку. Все уже написано и прекрасно работает, но вот как открыть эту страницу - не могу придумать...

Comment: Нельзя так сделать, нельзя. Потому что кнопки этой не существует, пока страницы нету.

Comment: Может возможно как-то просто передать скрипт на страницу ? Без ее открытия. Должен же быть выход !

Comment: Возможно, нужно его открыть но можно скрыть окно ?

Comment: За "нажатием на кнопку" скрываются какие-то действия. Скажем сбор неких данных со страницы, формирование запроса и отправка его на сервер. Вот сформировать запрос и отправить его на сервер - можно.

Comment: Нет, минимальные размеры окна по 100 px.

Comment: Политикой безопасности такое невозможно. Вы не можете внедрить свой код в чужую страницу, только если там нет дырки для XSS атак. Максимум, что вы можете, отправить ajax-запрос на какой-то сервер, который имеет эмулятор браузера с поддержкой JS и кликает там на нужные кнопки. Но это даже не костыль. Это идиотизм какой-то. :)

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо всем. Все понял.

Comment: открывать страницу в iframe 1x1px в рамках уже открытой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, если вы пишете расширение для google chrome, то там есть отличный метод инжектирование js кода на страничку ( политика безопасности тут не причем - это расширение ) Инжектируйте код, в котором будет вызов функции нужной вам
[Cтатейка на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147111/)